# Using whatsapp on two devices

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

One device has my Sim card, the other one only the internet connection. Both devices have already been verified by my number. Will I get incoming messagges in both devices?

Answer (score 1):

You're not allowed to do this, From whatsapp FAQ:

> Using one WhatsApp account on multiple phones, or with multiple phone numbers
>   Your WhatsApp account can only be verified with one number on one device. If you have a dual SIM phone, please note that you still must choose one number to verify with WhatsApp. There is no option to have a WhatsApp account with two phone numbers.
>
> If you attempt to frequently switch your WhatsApp account between different devices, at a certain point, you may be blocked from re-verifying your account. Please don't repeatedly switch between different devices and numbers.

Comment: What about theb phone without sim working on wifi? I read there whatsapp works and it would be a second device

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same WhatsApp account on more than one device at a time. As soon as you sign-in to a new device, the old one becomes invalidated.
WhatsApp does not support a 2nd device.

Comment: What if I dont need to sign up? I mean, it happened that when I changed the smartphone, I transferred all the back ups, the files... In the new device I didn't need to sign up to use whatsapp so I had whatsapp working both in the old and new device.. How is it possible?